# Render a different image depending on input in a ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a ShinyApp where different plots can be coloured based on several variables according to a `selectInput` panel, and a different image should  also be inserted depending on the user's selection on such panel.

I'm failing to be able to render the images. I just get a blank space where they should appear.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm still experimenting with shiny and just can't figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Relevant parts of my code (let me know if you need more):

Server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
     output$Imagen<- renderImage({
        if(input$ColorBy=="Raza") Leg<-"Razaimagen.png"
        if(input$ColorBy=="Log") Leg<-"Logimagen.png"

        list(src=Leg)
         })      
 })
```

UI:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
         fluidRow(
                  column(3, 
                         h3("Imagen", align = "center"),
                         imageOutput(outputId="Imagen")
            ))
        ))
```

"Razaimagen.png" and "Logimagen.png" are sitting happily in my `www` folder. They work well if I try eg `img(src="Razaimagen.png")` directly in the `ui.R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deleting the images, use:

```
  output$Imagen<- renderImage({
    if(input$ColorBy=="Raza") Leg<-"www/Razaimagen.png"
    if(input$ColorBy=="Log") Leg<-"www/Logimagen.png"
    list(src=Leg)
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
```

Comment: Tried that, no change. Any more ideas?

Comment: Try adding the www part of the relative path (updated answer), I've tried this with relative paths and It works for me

Comment: That was it. So simple. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing! glad I could help