# checkboxInput within mainPanel to display different images

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'd like to use a checkbox to select the image to output in a `mainPanel()` or `tabPanel()` in RShiny.

A reproducible example:

(to make it easier to run anywhere, we can replace "image1.png" with "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Apollonian_spheres.jpg" and "image2.png" with "https://community.rstudio.com/uploads/default/original/3X/5/1/51436f1a309c3aaeb71f5f580182029f2733a301.jpeg". I left as "image1.png" and "image2.png" for code cleanliness)

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot"),
                div(img(src="image1.png", width = 240, height = 190), style="text-align: center;"),
                div(img(src="image2.png", width = 240, height = 190), style="text-align: center;")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- rnorm(89,73,17)
        hist(x)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

produces:
[image]

I'd like to add `checkboxInput()` and an `if()` statement to the main panel so that one image is the default and the other displays if the checkbox is selected:

```
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
       plotOutput("distPlot"),
       checkboxInput(inputId = "test",value = F,label = "Image2"),
       if(input$test==F){
            div(img(src="image1.png", width = 240, height = 190), style="text-align: center;")
       }else{
            div(img(src="image2.png", width = 240, height = 190), style="text-align: center;")
       }
    )
```

The checkbox displays fine, but the if statements results in "object 'input' not found".

When I instead add the if statements to the server, and add an output, this results in 'output' not found.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30),
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot"),
           checkboxInput(inputId = "test",value = F,label = "Image2"),
            div(img(src=output$IMG, width = 240, height = 190), style="text-align: center;")
           
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- rnorm(89,73,17)
        hist(x)
        })

        if(input$test==F){
          output$IMG <- "image1.png"
        }else{
          output$IMG <- "image2.png"
        }

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Adding `reactive()` and `renderImage()` I remove the error messages, but no images display:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30),
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot"),
           checkboxInput(inputId = "test",value = F,label = "Image2"),
          
           renderImage(
             div(img(src=output$IMG, width = 240, height = 190), style="text-align: center;")
          )
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- rnorm(89,73,17)
        hist(x)
        })
        # output<-reactiveValues()
        
        reactive(
        if(input$test==F){
            output$IMG <- "image1.png"
        }else{
            output$IMG <- "image2.png"
        }
)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

After reading this great post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016939/9096420
I've played with many combinations of wrapping parts in `observeEvent()`, and I get the same thing.

```
observeEvent(input$test==F, {
    output$IMG <- renderImage(div(img(src="image1.png", width = 240, height = 190), style="text-align: center;"))
}),
observeEvent(input$test==T, {
    output$IMG <- renderImage(div(img(src="image2.png", width = 240, height = 190), style="text-align: center;"))
})
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `imageOutput()` and `"www/"` to the path name (based off https://stackoverflow.com/a/33636428/9096420) makes it work:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot"),
      checkboxInput(inputId = "test",value = F,label = "Image2"),
      imageOutput(outputId="Image")

    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- rnorm(89,73,17)
    hist(x)
  })

  output$Image<- renderImage({
    if(input$test==F){Choice<-"www/image1.png"}
    if(input$test==T){Choice<-"www/image2.png"}
    list(src=Choice)
  }, deleteFile = FALSE) 
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

[image]